# Divide line in multiple segments

Tags: matlab

Let's say I want to divide timeline in linearly growing chops ranging from 1" (starting value) to 10" (end value). If the sum is given (e.g. 120") I would like to know the value of each segment.
How do I calcutlate that in matlab?
Thank you!

Comment: Now that I've read the question properly... This is off-topic; you basically have a maths problem, not a programming problem.  The solution involves understanding [*arithmetic series*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_sequence#Sum).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Use the [`linspace()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html) function, which is for exactly this purpose.</s>

Comment: Are you sure? It's not trivial to use `linspace` if the number of segments is unknown.

Comment: oh, just one more question, if I would like to have some non linear growth between 2 values, how could I count that?

Comment: @EitanT: Oh, I completely misread the question!